# Redirect 301 www.example.com/directory/tour1 to www.example.com/tour1

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hi I have a situation with the mytic HTACCESS file. Im trying to fix a broken URL.
this folder never existed was a permalink created in WP.I need to redirect 301 all this broken links to avoid problems with Google.

The URL used to be like this

```
www.example.com/directory/tour1,   www.example.com/directory/tour2,   www.example.com/directory/tour3 and so on.
```

Now the url has changed so all the tours are under the root

```
 www.example.com/tour1, www.example.com/tour2...
```

I need to make that all the queries to www.example.com/directory/WHATEVER

to point to www.example.com/WHATEVER

Thanks for helping me understand this universe of redirections... \

i HAVE TRIED alot of codes, none of them does the job.

```
RewriteRule ^tulum-tours/(.*) http://www.aguaclaraproject.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess in your www-root use the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^tulum-tours/(.*)$ /$1 [R,L]
```

Change the R flag to R=301 after testing it works correctly. Read [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information.